# pymysql.err.ProgrammingError 1064 when executing command

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1064, pymysql

I just can't see a reason for this error. I have tried the same SQL in phpMyAdmin and it works perfectly fine, but fails when trying from Python.

**Python code with SQL query:**

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE marketPricesAvg SET avg%sh=(SELECT AVG(price) FROM marketPrices WHERE itemName = %s AND ((NOW() - marketPrices.datetime) < %s) WHERE itemName = %s)", (time, itemName, time_sec, itemName))
```

**Error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/marketprices/insert.py", line 42, in <module>
    calculate_avg(itemName, time)
  File "/root/marketprices/insert.py", line 29, in calculate_avg
    cursor.execute("UPDATE marketPricesAvg SET avg%sh=(SELECT AVG(price) FROM marketPrices WHERE itemName = %s AND ((NOW() - marketPrices.datetime) < %s) WHERE itemName = %s)", (time, itemName, time_sec, itemName))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 727, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1066, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 683, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE itemName = 'Aluminium')' at line 1")
```

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query fully qualified would look something like

```
UPDATE marketPricesAvg 
SET avg1234 = (
    SELECT AVG(price) FROM marketPrices 
    WHERE itemName = 'Aluminium' AND 
    ((NOW() - marketPrices.datetime) < '100') WHERE itemName = 'Aluminium'
);
```

Edit:
Should be

**(NOW() - marketPrices.datetime) < %s) WHERE itemName = %s**

The final parentheses is misplaced

Comment: Well, I have a table (marketPrices) containing a huge amount of data, where are columns like datetime, price, and itemName. In the second table (marketPricesAvg) I'm holding average values of the prices for each item.
The inner SELECT - WHERE takes prices from marketPrices table for the desired item and timespan.
Outer UPDATE then updates the rows in the marketPricesAvg. The reason for second WHERE is to only update the row which corresponds to the desired item.

Comment: Yes...your question about the WHERE clause let me look at it closely and then I saw it. Thanks.